# JavaScript sorting function unless I put Model.column and Model.order in quotation marks

Tags: javascript, razor-pages

I recently started learning c# and I'm doing a course on razor pages. I have a table of books and I want to be able to sort it by clicking on the column headings. This is my JavaScript function:

```
function sortTable(column)
{
    let order = "desc";
    let currentColumn = @Model.column;
    let currentOrder = @Model.order;

    if (column == currentColumn && currentOrder == "desc") 
    {
        order="asc";
    }

    window.location.href = "?search=@Model.search&column=" + column + "&order=" + order;
}
```

When I click on a heading, nothing happens. If I do the following instead, it works:

```
    let currentColumn = "@Model.column";
    let currentOrder = "@Model.order";
```

The variables are declared as strings in the model, so I really don't know why it isn't working.

Comment: _"The variables are declared as strings in the model"_ - so what? That is just their internal type. But you are _creating code_ here, so you need to abide by the rules of the syntax of the language you are creating code in. Text literals in JavaScript need some kind of quotes around them. Those quotes are not included in the _values_ of your variables (if the were, then you would also end up with `window.location.href = "?search="someSearchValue"&column=..."` there, which would make little sense), so you need to add them the moment you are trying to create code out of this data.

Comment: That makes sense. Feel free to add your comment as an answer if you want and I will definitely accept it. Thanks for the help @CBroe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The variables are declared as strings in the model

That is just their internal type. But you are *creating code* here, so you need to abide by the rules of the syntax of the language you are creating code *in*.

Text literals in JavaScript need some kind of quotes around them. Those quotes are not included in the values of your variables (if the were, then you would also end up with `window.location.href = "?search="someSearchValue"&column=..."` there, which would make rather little sense), so you need to add them the moment you are trying to create code out of this data.